# Google Analytics Enhanced Commerce Purchase

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm currently trying to track my new e-commerce application by the use of the enhanced commerce plugin from google analytics.

I got one weird tracking issue I don't understand.

Here's a screenshot from the [User Explorer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7025707/report.png)

This screenshot ist taken from the "User Explorer". Reffering to the screenshot, I'm expecting to see the correct EUR value and not just EUR 0,00€. So my problem is, that I'm adding the products correctly but I still just see EUR 0,00€ instead of (in this example) EUR 1.650,00.

However, if I check the details of this "event" you see products properly with it's quantity and price. I'm also sending the ec:revenue parameter set with the correct value for this transaction.

Here's my purchase action code:

```
commercePurchase: function (id, affiliation, revenue, shipping, tax) {
    console.log('GA Comerce Add Transaction: ', id, affiliation, revenue, shipping, tax) ;
    console.log('set action purchase!');
    ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
        'id': id,
        'affiliation': affiliation,
        'revenue': revenue,
        'tax': tax,
        'shipping': shipping
    });
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Regards,
Santo

Comment: Sorry, not following your problem as I don't see a clear problem statement. What's a "track"? Do you mean your data point? What's the `Purchase of XYZ` thing you're talking about? Can you include a screenshot from your reports?

Comment: Sure, see attached.

<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7025707/report.png)">

Comment: I'm just to dump to sf properly :/

[Report](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7025707/report.png)

By track I meant one page hit, one "event". So yeah, I guess you could call it a data point. > Purcahse of XYZ referes to > "Kauf von..." in my screenshot. I hope, this make stuff more clear :)

Comment: This screenshot ist taken from the "User Explorer" (in german it's called "Nutzer Explorer" so I'm guessing the english name).

Reffering to the screenshot, I'm expecting to see the correct EUR value and not just EUR 0,00€. So my problem is, that I'm adding the products correctly but I still just see EUR 0,00€ instead of (in this example) EUR 1.650,00. 

Did this make stuff more clear?

Comment: OK, thanks so much for clarifying! I think you should check your ecommerce hits using a tool like GA Debugger (for Chrome) to verify that your hits are going through to GA. Alternatively, you could check your hits to GA from the dev console. Make sure they all look fine. I'm curious where your screenshot is from though. I don't recognize that report in GA.

Comment: It is taken straight from the User Explorer. I already checked with the GA Chrome Debugger and ec:revenue is beeing set correctly. Any other parameter I might be missing out?

Comment: I'm assuming you also have the `ga('ec:addProduct'...` parameters and finally the `ga('send', 'pageview');` as well?

Comment: Not using pageview but an event `ga('send', eventData);` . According to the documentation the result will be the same. And yes, I am adding the products upfront. This is the weird seeing. As you can see in the screenshots, the products with its attributes (quantity and price) are present but just this user explorer thingy displays EUR 0 :/

Comment: Hm..looks like there could be a mismatch of the data you're sending and the ecommerce step. For example, the shopping cart symbol should indicate a checkout step (ie. Checkout, Add to cart, Detail view), but you have a "Payment" action (meaning it should be the actual purchase or transaction). http://pasteboard.co/56tunYnaZ.png.

Comment: How did you do that? Could you pastebin me your Code?